# Managing UV layers in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, uv-mapping

I've defined distinct UV mapping for a given geometry. The first mapping is located in geometry.faceVertexUvs[0], ie, "the first layer". Logically, I used the other layers (ie, 1, 2, etc.) for the other mappings. Later, at animation time , I want to tell Three.js using a given layer between 0, 1, etc. Apart from missing something, I didn't find the way to simply doing this.

Note : my mesh has only one material. It's confusing in my mind: the possibility of having multiple UV layers is linked (or not at all) to the fact that I endow my geometry with several materials? Thanks for ideas.